# WSO2 EI : <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text> is not working in wso2 and the output remains in same line

Tags: xslt, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am working on one transformation from xml to csv using xslt. All the code is working fine but I need to add a new line after one record and for that I am using  in the xslt code.

```
<xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
```

Even after adding 
 , still the result are coming into single line. Also,

```
&#xA;
```

gets disappear from the xslt code.
Can some one please guide how to add a line at the end of the record in xslt in wso2 EI.

Thanks in advance. Can someone please check

Comment: If u used to use web-admin to edit xslt local entry, web version of editor cut xml entities. Most probably due trying escape unsafe code. Do edit in text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the local entry file from backend where the file is deployed and made the changed with &#10. The file was locally updated as well and when ran the code the entries were there in new lines as it should be.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `<xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>`?

Save it to a .xslt file and package it into a .car file and deploy that to the your wso2 EI.

Also be wary of what operating system you are writing the file to and what program you are using to view the file. If you are using Windows and viewing the file with notepad even though there are new line characters notepad will still display everything on one line.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But even though .xslt file was created and packaged in .car file the same issue was there. I found an alternate way to do this.